# Verification of a proof for tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, trees

We have to prove that if a graph $G$ with $n$ nodes is connected and has exactly $n-1$ edges then it is a tree.

**Proof:** By contradiction. Assume $G$ is not a tree and thus it must have at least one cycle. Removing an edge $e$ from a cycle we get $G'$ which is connected and has $n-2$ edges. As $G'$ is connected, degree of each node is at least $1$. Therefore sum of degrees of all nodes is at least $n$. Hence:

$2(n-2) \ge n$ which is not true for $n \le 3$ and we reach a contradiction.

Will this proof be considered correct? I am confused because if we take $n \ge 4$ then it will fail.

**EDIT:**

**Proof(2):** By induction.
$P(n):=$ If $G$ is a graph with $n$ nodes and has exactly $n-1$ edges then it is a tree.

Base case: For $n=1$, we have a graph with $1$ node and $0$ edges which is a tree by definition.

Consider a graph $G$ with $n$ nodes and $n-1$ edges, it is a tree by inductive hypothesis. Add a vertex $v$ and an edge $e$ to $G$ such that $e$ connects $v$ and a leaf node $u$ in $G$. This graph we obtain has $n+1$ nodes and $n$ edges and is still connected and doesn't have a cycle and thus is a tree.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not correct. If it were, the same method could prove that a connected graph with exactly $2n-100$ edges is a tree.

Comment: Show a graph with n > 1 nodes and n - 2 edges is disconnected.

Comment: Is proof 2 correct? @WilliamElliot And thanks, I will try that.